# Nodejs remote debugging ports closed

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, node.js

I have a problem with nodejs remote debugging. I'm using centos on remote server and phpstorm on my PC.
When I open putty: I type in command:

*node --debug-brk=5858 main_server.js*,

and the output is:

*debugger listening on port 5858*.

Next thing I do is go to edit configuration in phpstorm, and choose *remotehost:8585*. When I'm trying to connect, it pops up:

*connecting to remoteserver:8585*

*connection refused*.

What I have done so far is to add port 8585 and 5858 to centos firewall with adding lines to iptables:

*-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5858 -j ACCEPT*

*-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8585 -j ACCEPT*

After that I tried another solution, because I saw in documentation that I need to set up port forwarding:

*yum install balance -yt*

*balance -df 8585 127.0.0.1.5858*

and tried port forwarding with this command

*iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 --dport 5858 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:5858*

The solutions I tried were: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752362/node-js-on-virtualbox-centos-machine-no-connection and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445534/how-to-remote-debug-node-js-with-phpstorm.

I also opened ports on my local network router and Windows firewall, but I don't know if I have a good logic.
What is detailed procedure for enabling nodejs remote debugging on centos server, which ports do I need to open, where exactly (remote server and LAN), do I need port forwarding, and what I need to do in order to make nodejs remote debugging work?

Answer (score 0):

From your configuration it seems the node debugger is listening on port 5858, but in your phpStorm settings you have 8585.